# What is a host? [not on the internet]

Tags: io, driver, cpu, host

I am reading some literature on IO devices, and I've come up to this sentence:

> ... Host is trying to read data bit ...
>
> The complete protocol for interaction between the host and controller can be intricate, but the basic handshaking notion is simple

What is exactly a host, CPU, driver, something else?

Comment: most probably http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_controller

Comment: The complete protocol for interaction between the host and controller can be intricate, but the basic handshaking notion is simple

This confuses me, it sounds like it's CPU, right?